# SDK for .NET Forge Data Management search items API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

Does anybody have already built an SDK for .NET, using the filters and find items calls for the Forge Data Management API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check the NuGet we have for Forge? https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autodesk.Forge/

I'm not sure if it contains the calls you are requesting but you could use this to build it yourself.

Comment: Hello Jaime, thanks for your response. I'm using this Nuget version, but we don't have some code example to use this API endpoint:

https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-folders-folder_id-search-GET/